# dstore filter date range

Tags: javascript, date, filter, dojo, dstore

I have a data array which has a `date` attribute, I need to filter the data based on date.

I am using `dstorejs` to store the data as below

```
this.employeeStore = new Memory({data:[emplist],idProperty:"emp_num"});
```

I need to make a filter based on employee's joining date , like who joined from 1st of Jan 2014 till 3rd of March 2015

```
this.employeeStore.filter({joinDate:'01/01/2014'});
```

This gives all employees who joined on 1st of Jan 2014 but if I need to filter in a range like

```
this.employeeStore.filter.gte({joinDate:'01/01/2014'});
```

This will not work because it is not a number, it is a `string` or `date` object

To achieve this do I need to write the custom store as they mentioned in [tutorial](http://dstorejs.io/tutorials/custom_stores.html)?

Is there any other way of doing this?

Or is there any other framework like `dstore` to achieve this ?

Comment: Your date are string formatted ? or Date type ?

Comment: You mention `dstorejs` but in your example you are using `Memory`, is this correct?

Comment: @Kstro dstore has the Memory "dstore/Memory"

Comment: @bRIMOsBor need to put in Date type, just for example i have written in String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this just by using `dojo/store` [Query filter](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/store.html) , 
exactly query with callback function to manage comparing date

and also using the `dojo/date` `compare` function to compare date of your emplist array to a specific date like below :

```
this.employeeStore = new Memory({data: someData});

var compareDate = new Date(2014,1,1);

var results = store.query(function(object){
    // compare return -1 if lower 
    // return 0 if equals
    // return 1 if greater
    return date.compare(object.date, compareDate) > -1;
});

results.forEach(function(yourResultData){
    // some stuff looping results
});
```

you can see a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eq1xsx19/1/) to have a better understanding .

Comment: thanks i came to know in dojo also has this.. instead of dstorejs we can use dojo/store